# kubectl get nodes` returns `The connection to the server 10.xxxxxxxxx was refused

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces

it gives kubectl get nodes returns 'The connection to the server 10.xxxxxxxxx was refused. did you specify right host or port?'

kindly do guide.

thanks

Comment: fix you kubeconfig file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your kubeconfig is not correct after doing kubeadm init, you didnt do the below steps.

```
Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!
To start using your cluster, you need to run (as a regular user):
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

Try it and check

If you are on GKE try doing below steps to autogenerate kubeconfig

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "CLUSTER NAME"
```